# Performance issue when upgrading from HornetQ to Artemis ActiveMQ

Tags: hornetq, activemq-artemis

Has anyone experienced performance degradation when upgrading from HornetQ to Active Artemis?  I'm working on a system that upgraded from HornetQ 2.4.5.Final to Artemis 2.10.0 and am seeing a performance degradation.  Beginning investigation, but so far it appears the configuration/setup is similar between the two.

Comment: Please share some metrics regarding to the performance degradation, as well as configuration/setup data, and all other relevant information related to your issue!

Comment: Do you have any further details to add for this performance issue?

Answer (score 1):

There have been lots of performance enhancements made to ActiveMQ Artemis since the donation of the HornetQ code-base to Apache so if anything I would expect it to be faster. However, there's certainly a chance that a particular use-case could be slower, and there's always the possibility of bugs.

It's worth noting that HornetQ 2.4.5.Final was tagged in October 2014 (the same month & year as the donation to Apache) and ActiveMQ Artemis 2.10.0 was tagged in August 2019 which is about 5 years difference. That's a significant gap in the life of an active software project. There have been over 7,000 commits to the ActiveMQ Artemis code-base during that time.

You would really need to describe your use-case in detail and quantify the performance degradation for any real investigation to be done.